# Getting user information in DbContext

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, dbcontext

I am attempting to use EF migrations to build/seed my database but my DbContext is causing an error when I use the update-database command.

The DbContext I have implemented has two constructors: one accepts no arguments and the other accepts an IUserContext interface. The IUserContext interface returns a username as a string. The IUserContext is used in the SaveChanges() method for setting user-related audit fields (ex. CreatedBy, UpdatedBy) common to all of my entities. Depending on the implementation of the IUserContext interface, the username may be retrieved from a HttpContext (in a mvc app), WindowsIdentity (in a console app), etc.

If a user attempts to call SaveChanges on the DbContext and the IUserContext is not set, it throws an exception. Basically, ***I do not want changes saved in the DbContext if a username cannot be provided by the IUserContext interface for purposes of recording who is making the modifications.*** If the DbContext is being used just for querying, using the no-args constructor isn't an issue since IUserContext is only used during SaveChanges.

When I attempt to use the update-database command, the DbMigrationsConfiguration is given an instance of the DbContext instantiated using the no-args constructor. Therefore, it throws an exception when it tries to invoke the DbContext's SaveChanges after the Seed() method.

Question: ***How do I pass an IUserContext to my DbContext so the update-database command will not fail and, more importantly, be able to set the appropriate entity fields to the name of the user seeding the changes?*** Is there some form of DI or other customization I can perform in the DbMigrationsConfiguration? Should I simply add an IUserContext accessor method to the DbContext so the IUserContext can be set outside of the constructor?

Maybe I should be asking a larger question: ***What is the best (most generic?) way of relaying user information to a DbContext for the purposes of recording who is making modifications***?

I gave some thought about moving this logic to the business layer of my application but it seems so convenient to encapsulate it in the SaveChanges of the DbContext (even more so when change tracking is enabled) .

Answer (score 0):

We have a similar situation where we record modified user in SaveChanges() override. What we ended up doing was creating a BaseWrapper and use IoC to fill it. The second part is creating a MigrationsContextFactory that migrations will use to create the context. This class lives in the same folder as our ApplicationDbContext.

```
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;

namespace MyApp.Data
{
    public class MigrationsContextFactory : IDbContextFactory<ApplicationDbContext>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext Create()
        {
            return new ApplicationDbContext(new HttpContextBaseWrapper());
        }
    }
}

public class HttpContextBaseWrapper : IHttpContextBaseWrapper
{
    public string UserName
    {
        get
        {
            if (HttpContext.Current == null || HttpContext.Current.User == null)
                return string.Empty;
            return HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
        }
    }
}
```

https://marazt.wordpress.com/2015/01/09/entity-framework-dbcontext-idbcontextfactory-and-codefirst-migration-problem/